# A DataReader associated with this command is already open. It must first be closed

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I try to insert some values into  a table but this error occurs A DataReader associated with this command is already open. It must first be closed
this is the code

```
Public Function AddDB(ByVal codeP As String, ByVal exigence As String, ByVal nomE As String, ByVal Dt As String)
    OpenCn()
    Dim paramID As New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
    paramID.Value = 10
    Dim paramText As New SqlParameter("@text", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
    paramText.Value = "Ceci est un test"
    Dim paramDate As New SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    paramDate.Value = DateTime.Now
    Dim paramFloat As New SqlParameter("@float", SqlDbType.Float)
    paramFloat.Value = 12.199999999999999

    Dim Sql As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO DossierBleu(CodeP, Exigences, NomE, Date) VALUES (@codeP, @exigence, @nomE, @date)",
        paramText.ParameterName,
            paramText.ParameterName,
            paramText.ParameterName,
            paramText.ParameterName,
            paramDate.ParameterName
          )


    Dim Cmd = New SqlCommand(Sql.ToString(), Cn)
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@codeP", codeP))
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@exigence", exigence))
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nomE", nomE))
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@date", Dt))
    'Cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDate)
    Return Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    CloseCn()
End Function
```

thank you

Comment: You might want to look at the using statement... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx It's a more robust way of making sure that your objects (such as the connection, reader) get closed correctly even if an exception happens.

Answer (score 0):

if you use at least SQL Server 2005 then add

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

to your connection string.

Comment: thank u for  your answer but I m biginner and I don't know where to find the connection string if u can help pliiz thank u

Comment: The connection string contains the name of the DB you connect to, username and password. It must be somewhere in your App. Here are some examples: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: is it here where to add it ??
Public Cn As New SqlConnection("server=" & ServerName & "; initial catalog=" & dataBaseName & " ; integrated security= true")

Comment: Yes. Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to it like this: `...dataBaseName & " ; integrated security= true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")`